# How to change default geo position in Nox app player

Tags: android, android-emulator

How to change in nox app player default geo in google map ? Because after create new emulator need every time change pin on google map.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

c:\Users\YOURUSERNAME\AppData\Local\Nox\conf.ini

```
   [Location]


Lat=10.8378886



Lng=106.638701



Map=google
```

Answer (score 0):

For **Nox** emulator you can setup location and status GPS in files placed on android:

```
> adb shell ls /data/property/persist.nox.gps.*
/data/property/persist.nox.gps.latitude
/data/property/persist.nox.gps.longitude
/data/property/persist.nox.gps.status
```